# Send initial value to parent component

Tags: reactjs

I have a child component where I pass data and logic inside the child component works out the initial value.  I am having trouble figuring out the right way to send the initial value back to the parent component without duplicating the logic inside the parent component.

To demonstrate the issue I have created the following contrived example:

(Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-dream-err7b?file=/src/App.jsx)

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const data = [23, 57, 92];

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);

  function handleSelect(selected) {
    setSelected(selected);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Selected is: {selected}</h1>
      <Child data={data} onSelect={handleSelect} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Child({ data, onSelect }) {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(Math.max(...data));

  function handleChange(e) {
    onSelect(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <select
        onChange={handleChange}
        defaultValue={selectedValue}
        name="test"
        id="test"
      >
        {data.map((number, i) => {
          return (
            <option key={i} value={number}>
              {number}
            </option>
          );
        })}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The value is sent fine when a change occurs but how can parent know what initial value was selected?  So in the example the page will render with 92 being output in the title.

Comment: [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-sea-16sv5?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Is there any specific reason why do not use attribute `value` on the select element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use useEffect() function in your child component.

```
useEffect(() => {
    onSelect(selectedValue);
}, []);
```

New code :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const data = [23, 57, 92];

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);

  function handleSelect(selected) {
    setSelected(selected);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Selected is: {selected}</h1>
      <Child data={data} onSelect={handleSelect} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Child({ data, onSelect }) {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(Math.max(...data));

  useEffect(() => {
    onSelect(selectedValue);
  }, []);

  function handleChange(e) {
    onSelect(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <select
        onChange={handleChange}
        defaultValue={selectedValue}
        name="test"
        id="test"
      >
        {data.map((number, i) => {
          return (
            <option key={i} value={number}>
              {number}
            </option>
          );
        })}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to pass the initial value from the parent component.

Second use `useEffect` hook to call `onSelect` on the component's mount.

But I think the first solution is better, as the child component will be more flexible and clear.

You can set up the initial value in the parent component and pass it as a prop

```
const initialValue = useMemo(() => Math.max(...data), [])
```